# Sorting table in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm quite new to vue.js, so I have a problem sorting my table by spend amount. I would like to have an opportunity to sort it by highest or lowest spend on campaigns.
I have made the following code, to try and sort my table. However, this code is not working.

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <h1> Campaign performance </h1>
        <table class="table table-sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Client</th>
                    <th scope="col">Mediachannel</th>
                    <th scope="col">Campaign</th>
                    <th scope="col">Spend</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(campaign, name) in campaignPerformance" :key="campaign.campaignID">
                 <td>{{campaign.client}}</td>
                 <td>{{campaign.mediaChannel}}</td>
                 <td>{{campaign.campaign}}</td>
                 <td>{{campaign.spend}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</div></template>
<script>
import axios from'axios';
export default {
  data() {
   return {
    };
  },
props: ['campaignPerformance'],
components: {},
methods: {
 sortTable() {
  this.campaign.spend.sort((a,b) => a.rating < b.rating ? 1 : -1); //Just tried to sort by highest spend 
  },
},
computed: {
 filteredCampaigns() {
  let filter = new RegExp(this.filterText, 'i')
  return this.campaign.spend.filter(el => el.campaign.campaign.match(filter))
}
},
created() {},
};
</script>
```

Any help would be appriciated to get this code to work, or suggestions on other ways to sort the table!

Comment: error in console?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the sort function it depends which way you want to sort it.

If a is less than b and you want them to be in that order in the list then output -1 not 1

see this example

```
this.campaign.spend.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.rating === b.rating)  return 0
    if (a.rating < b.rating) return -1
    if (a.rating > b.rating) return 1
})
```